# Ssh config for Jenkins when using helm and k8s

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, ssh-config

So I have a k8s cluster and I am trying to deploy Jenkins using the following repo https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts.

The main issue is I am working behind a proxy and when git tried to pull (using the ssh protocol) it is failing.

I am able to get around this by building my own docker image from the provided, installing socat and using the following .ssh/config in the container:

```
Host my.git.repo
  # LogLevel DEBUG
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  ProxyCommand /usr/bin/socat - PROXY:$HOST_PROXY:%h:%p,proxyport=3128
```

Is there a better way to do this, I was hoping to use the provided image and perhaps have a plugin thast allowed something similar, but everywhere I look I can't seem to find anything.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What are the versions of your Helm and K8s? Where is your cluster located? Is there any error message that you see when trying to achieve your goal?